# UDP send always end ups in the catch

Tags: java, android, udp

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                String host = "192.168.4.1";
                int port = 2390;
                byte[] message = "Som tu".getBytes();
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, address, port);
                DatagramSocket dSocket = new DatagramSocket();
                dSocket.send(packet);
                dSocket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                speak("error");
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,3);
            mySpeechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
        }
    });
```

Im trying to create android app that will send text via udp when buttuon is pressed but it always end up in the catch .. any thoughts why ? I also get Error: E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc but I dont know how to fix it.
Is there any permission that Im forgetting about ? Im using only (RECORD_AUDIO,INTERNET)

Comment: If you throw away the exception information ( `speak("error");` ) we can only guess what the problem is.  Print out the exception stacktrace and show it to us.  Better still, read it first.  The exception name and message will probably sufficient to tell **you** what the problem is without you needing to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I assume you´re getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Android does not allow network activity on its main thread in order to keep an app responsive. To avoid this error, start a new thread inside your `onClick` method and perform the network activity there

Comment: I would like to advice to always log your exception to have a better understanding of what goes wrong. In this case you are catching almost each and every exception and it is not logged, so there are numerous things that could have failed. You can, for example, add `Log.e("CRASH", "Exception occurred: ", e)` to your catch, to have your error logged and get more information about what goes wrong